# MySQL-How to upgrade all client programs to use a 4.1.1

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, mysql-connector

In Visual Studio, I downloaded the latest version of MySql connector, but when I am trying to enter the credentials and choose the db, before I even can do this, it says:

> "Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords"

I'm using Hostgator and I filed a ticket with them asking them what to do. He said the best solution is to upgrade all client programs to use a 4.1.1 version.

What does he mean by this? Is there something on the client side to upgrade? Mysql and PHP are server side, and I thought host gator would take care of all that.

As far as the Mysql connector goes, I'm using version 6.6.5. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing to do with clients. MySQL had two different ways of hashing passwords ('old' and 'new'), and your PW hashes are in the 'old' style. You'll have to change your PW to use the new style, e.g.

```
SET SESSION old_passwords=0;
SET PASSWORD FOR user@host=PASSWORD('your pw here');
```

You will have to do this for every password. The hashes are 1-way and cannot be changed to the new style directly.

Comment: Is this something I can do or host gator has to do it?

Comment: you can do it. it's just a "query", even if it doesn't look like a select/update-type one.

Comment: Workbench begins to work after following this method but if you are using the entity framework like I am then this did not resolve it. EF says password no longer supported use 4.1 style password.